# stopPropagation and live() method. What am I missing?

Tags: events, jquery, stoppropagation

I've read jQuery doc and I know that there's no point in using stopPropagation() if I use live() to bind event to elements, as the event with live() binds to document node so the event has already spred up. Said so, I figured nex code would alert 3 times,as stopPropagation doesn't stop anything:

```
<ul style="border:red solid 1px;">
    <li style="padding:10px; border:blue solid 1px;">
        <p style="border:green solid 1px;"><a href="#">link</a></p>
    </li>
    <li style="padding:10px; border:blue solid 1px;">
        <p style="border:green solid 1px;">no link</p>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').live( "click", function( e ) {alert("link");e.stopPropagation()} );
    $('ul').live( "click", function( e ) {alert("ul");} );
    $('ul li').live( "click", function( e ) {alert("li");} );
</script>
```

When I click  link I expected and alert of "li" and "ul", however stopPropagation is stopping the other events when it was supposed to be useless.
What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just `$('a').on( "click", function() {alert("link"); return false;} );`?

Comment: Your code works as expected if i click on the exact link. I do not see the ul and li alerts. If i click on the space next to the actual link, i see the other two alerts. You might want to set widths to the elements so that you do not see this behavior.

Comment: Seems like it's because for ul and ul li you also used `live`. If you change them to `bind` they're both called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) `stopPropagation()` does not work in `live()` as expected as `live()` only executes the event after it already bubbled up to the `document`.

However, if you are using jQuery 1.4.3 or later `stopPropagation()` started working.

`live()` was re-written several times since 1.4.3.
The `live()` documentation lists a lot of reasons why using other binding methods instead is preferred. It seems though that the information in the documentation refers to the 1.4.1 behaviour and doesn't seem to be 100% in sync with the actual current behaviour.

For example looking at the 1.7.1 Source which added `on()` it shows `live()` is using `on()`:

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pcmtr/) - Using your code and live in jQuery 1.4.1 - stopPropagation is not working, as expected

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JwPte/) - Using your code and live in jQuery 1.4.3 - stopPropagation is now working

#### Summary

`live()` was re-written in 1.4.3. I assume due to `delegate()` having been added then.
`live()` has continuesly been updated with each version of jQuery as improvements were added.

In general to prevent any surprising results with `live()` it is better to follow the guidelines from the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and use the suggested methods for a given version of jQuery:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

---

For completness I have added the `live()` source extract for 1.4.1 and 1.4.3 below.

#### 1.4.1 source

```
live: {
    add: function(proxy, data, namespaces, live) {
        jQuery.extend(proxy, data || {});

        proxy.guid += data.selector + data.live;
        data.liveProxy = proxy;

        jQuery.event.add(this, data.live, liveHandler, data);

    },

    remove: function(namespaces) {
        if (namespaces.length) {
            var remove = 0,
                name = new RegExp("(^|\\.)" + namespaces[0] + "(\\.|$)");

            jQuery.each((jQuery.data(this, "events").live || {}), function() {
                if (name.test(this.type)) {
                    remove++;
                }
            });

            if (remove < 1) {
                jQuery.event.remove(this, namespaces[0], liveHandler);
            }
        }
    },
    special: {}
}
```

#### 1.4.3 source

```
live: {
    add: function(handleObj) {
        jQuery.event.add(this, liveConvert(handleObj.origType, handleObj.selector), jQuery.extend({}, handleObj, {
            handler: liveHandler,
            guid: handleObj.handler.guid
        }));
    },

    remove: function(handleObj) {
        jQuery.event.remove(this, liveConvert(handleObj.origType, handleObj.selector), handleObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's [not working in 1.4.3](http://jsfiddle.net/WA9as/), anyway I downvoted because 90% of your post is misguided that `live` is somehow different from delegation

Comment: @Esailija: I have added DEMO's showing it work in 1.4.1 and a comment regarding the the change in 1.4.3. In 1.4.3 `live()` was re-written, most likely due to the fact `delegate()` was added then. `live()` was added in 1.4.1 in which `stopPropagation()` did not work as expected. In 1.4.3 `delegate()` was added superceeding `live()`. I assume that is why jQuery `live()` was re-written with every release if an improvement was available. For convinience I also added the source for live in 1.4.1 and 1.4.3.

Comment: This behavior is still weird and unintuitive, they are all bound to `document` and only handled on `document`, only `e.stopImmediatePropagation` *should* have an effect. For example, this should be equivalent, yet it isn't. http://jsfiddle.net/PHvVh/

Comment: @Esailija: I totally agree. It is strange. I also couldn't find anything in the documentation for `live()` regarding the changes of live throughout the versions, making some of the bullet points the documentation raises on what doesn't work in `live()` redundant and confusing.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I thought I might be missing something, but it turns out depending on jquery ver. same method is working different.